# Can't get Twitter gem search results in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, twitter

Still very new to Rails. How do I call my method in calltwitter.rb file located in my lib folder from my model? Basically I want the array returned from the calltwitter.rb into my model so I can store it.

I have these two classes:

lib/twitter/calltwitter.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

class CallTwitter

  def search(search_string)

    Twitter.search(search_string, :rpp => 5, :lang => "en", :result_type => "mixed").map do |result|
      search_tweets << {:image_url => result.profile_image_url, :from_user => result.from_user, :tweet => result.text, :tweeteddate => result.created_at}
    end

  return search_tweets
end
```

and

```
require './lib/twitter/CallTwitter.rb'

class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base

  def get_search_tweets
    search_tweets = CallTwitter.new
    search_tweets.search("search string")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use "self" like so:

```
def self.get_search_tweets
  search_tweets = CallTwitter.new
  search_tweets.search("search string")
end
```

Also had to reload the rails console.

```
rails c
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but could you please try
**edit this in config/application.rb  Hope it will help.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/twitter/CallTwitter.rb)
```